# Use dplyr to update blank levels of factor given matches in other factor levels

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df <- read.table(sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
text = "
plantfam,lepfam,lepsp\n
             Asteraceae,Geometridae,Eois sp\n
             Asteraceae,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae,Noctuidae,\n
             Asteraceae,Saturnidae,Polyphemous sp\n
             Melastomaceae,Noctuidae,\n
             Asteraceae,,\n
             Melastomaceae,,\n
             ,Noctuidae,\n
             ,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae, Erebidae,\n")
```

I would like to make unique `lepsp` names conditional on the unique combinations of `plantfam` and `lepfam`. Each lepfam must first be subsetted. And for each unique `plantfam` `lepfam` combo within that lepfam subset a morpho species name is designated. For those where plantfam or lepfam are blank, a morpho species is not designated. Duplicate `plantfam` `lepfam` combos should be given the same morpho species name. The output should look like:

```
output<- 
 plantfam        lepfam                      lepsp
 Asteraceae      Geometridae                 Eois sp         
 Asteraceae      Erebidae                    Erebidae_morphosp1                 
 Poaceae         Erebidae                    Erebidae_morphosp2
 Poaceae         Noctuidae                   Noctuidae_morphosp1      
 Asteraceae      Saturnidae                  Polyphemous sp        
 Melastomaceae   Noctuidae                   Noctuidae_morphosp2
 Asteraceae             
 Melastomaceae   
                 Noctuidae
                 Erebidae
 Poaceae          Erebidae                    Erebidae_morphosp2
```

I have tried:

```
condition <- quote(lepsp == "" & plantfam != "" & lepfam != "")
subset1 <- df %>% filter(condition) %>% group_by(lepfam) %>% 
mutate(lepsp= 
paste0(lepfam,"_morphosp",match(plantfam,unique(plantfam))))
subset2 <- df %>% filter(condition) %>% setdiff(df, .)
union(subset1, subset2) %>% arrange(lepsp)
```

However the two lines with `Poaceae` and  `Erebidae`return different morphosp numbers `Erebidae_morphosp1` and `Erebidae_morphosp2` when they should be the same.

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
Groups: lepfam [6]

                     plantfam      lepfam               lepsp
                        <chr>       <chr>               <chr>
1                   Melastomaceae                                
2                      Asteraceae                                
3                         Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
4                      Asteraceae Geometridae             Eois sp
5                      Asteraceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1
6                         Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp2
7                                    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp3
8                         Poaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1
9                   Melastomaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp2
10                                  Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp3
11                     Asteraceae  Saturnidae      Polyphemous sp
```

Comment: What's `condition`?

Comment: For those `lepsp` which are blank and have  `plantfam` and `lepfam`  names associate with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue might only be that that in your `df`, the very last line has a space before Erebidae, which leads R to think it's different from the other one.

I found that while I was finishing my answer. Here' how I would do what you want to do. I introduce a group number `lepfam_number` before the `mutate` to paste.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(lepfam) %>%
  mutate(lepfam_number= match(plantfam, unique(plantfam)),
         lepsp=ifelse(lepsp=="" & lepfam!="" & trimws(plantfam)!="",
               paste0(lepfam,"_morphosp",lepfam_number),
               lepsp)
  )

                     plantfam      lepfam               lepsp lepfam_number
                        <chr>       <chr>               <chr>         <int>
1                  Asteraceae Geometridae             Eois sp             1
2                  Asteraceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp1             1
3                     Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp2             2
4                     Poaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp1             1
5                  Asteraceae  Saturnidae      Polyphemous sp             1
6               Melastomaceae   Noctuidae Noctuidae_morphosp2             2
7                  Asteraceae                                             1
8               Melastomaceae                                             2
9                               Noctuidae                                 3
10                               Erebidae                                 3
11                    Poaceae    Erebidae  Erebidae_morphosp2             2
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                 text = "
plantfam,lepfam,lepsp\n
             Asteraceae,Geometridae,Eois sp\n
             Asteraceae,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae,Noctuidae,\n
             Asteraceae,Saturnidae,Polyphemous sp\n
             Melastomaceae,Noctuidae,\n
             Asteraceae,,\n
             Melastomaceae,,\n
             ,Noctuidae,\n
             ,Erebidae,\n
             Poaceae,Erebidae,\n")
```

Comment: Nice catch! If you have a moment, I'm trying to understand the way `match` is working here. As I understand it, *Poaceae* is position 2 in `unique(plantfam)`. In rows 3 and 4, it is considered 2 and 1- is that because of the preceding `group_by(lepfam)`? Maybe I'm misunderstanding `group_by`? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LukeC Yes, because I group by lepfam first, unique(plantfam) will always be 2 for Poaceae in that specific group.

Comment: @P Lapointe Got it, that makes sense- thank you for clarifying!